# How do I install xen hypervisor + linux onto a usb memory stick

Tags: linux, xen

I'm wanting to create a bootable Linux + Xen Hypervisor on a USB stick.

I have it working how I want on a hard drive but for cloud deployment I'd like it to boot xen to a ram disk and mount the internal hard drive to /xen

The idea being that I can deploy new xen servers by just plugging in a USB stick.

How would I go about getting linux and xen onto a USB stick?  I'm looking for some good tutorials but haven't found that many that suit. Apart from ones that convert ISO boot CD images to USB.

Note: I am not interested in answers that show me how to put xenserver on a usb stick.  Xenserver is not linux + xen hypervisor.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Most usb sticks just show up as a regular /dev/sdx, so you should be able to pick that as a drive and install onto it.  If the installer does not want to work with a non-hdd, you can always make a ext{2,3,4} partition on the USB stick and make it boot with EXTLINUX, point it at the hypervisor, and let it boot.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, just been researching on common methods.  I think I will attempt to do it as you state.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Apline Linux Live XEN iso is what you are looking for

[Alpine Linux Downloads](http://alpinelinux.org/downloads)

Comment: just tried, the boot fails somewhere after the first steps with xen.gz things..

Answer (score 1):

As i can see this thread is still alive, so, maybe, my answer will help someone. I recently stucked with similar problem and it was hard to me to create a bootable USB. Boot hanged or USB wasn't properly identified. I haven't found the reason of problem, but i suppose it's related with UEFI, because OS images i used started properly from VMs... I have managed to create a bootable USB with latest Alpine Xen iso image using [Easy 2 Boot tool](http://www.easy2boot.com/). E2B i installed on flash using Windows7 VM. On XP VM i got some errors while installing it. On Ubuntu 12.04 i tryied a lot of startup disk creator tools and none of them worked for 100% sure.

Comment: In the end I managed to create a netbootable version of xen.  Then the images were stored on ceph.